# Unity dislikes the JDK it installed

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I'm making an Android game with Unity. When I try to generate my keystore, Unity complains about the JDK that I installed from the Unity Hub? Tried switching it out for another OpenJDK, didn't work. Tried reinstalling Unity, didn't work. Anyone got some tips?

Comment: I would post more details in order to make the question useful for someone else. Like JDK versions

Comment: Thanks for the advice, gonna add that now...

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by downloading a specific version of Oracle JDK 8. I think the version was JDK 8_u77 or something like that. Basically I just selected the JDK path in my project to my newly installed JDK and everything worked perfectly.